# How to create "striped" border using CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

I am making my own website design (for php fusion), and I can't figure how to do the striped border around the whole content. Better look at the picture:

https://greart.sk/uploads/download/preview/0743c0b917b78a5012c15e7c861f5482.png

If you don't know which one I mean, look closer.

https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2018/01/14/08Vu.png

Can it be done, just via CSS?

I tried this, but cant do the striped borders, maybe via background-image that will repeat, or I don't know:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
<div>

.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red; 
}

#content {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider a pseudo element with a repeated linear-gradient like this:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://lorempixel.com/g/800/800/');
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

#content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 45%, #000 45%, #000 55%, transparent 55%) 0 0/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 45%, #000 45%, #000 55%, transparent 55%) 5px 0px/10px 10px;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div>
```